# Switch statement in Js

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I just learned about the switch statement and Ive been trying it out. I have some questions about it. First I want to talk about something I tried out that didn't work. I am not sure why it doesn't work, especially because it doesn't cause any error message in the console log thing. Here it is:

```html
<p id="goonga"></p>

<script>
    var currnc = ""
    var rngab = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    switch (rngab) {
        case "1":
          currnc = "Yen";
          break;
        case "2":
          currnc = "Dollar";
          break;
        case "3":
          currnc = "Peso";
          break;
        case "4":
          currnc = "Pound";
          break;
        case "5":
          currnc = "Bolivar";
          break;
        case "6":
          currnc = "Rupee";
          break;
        case "7":
          currnc = "Euro";
          break;
        case "8":
          currnc = "Bitcoin";
          break;
        case "9":
          currnc = "Monopoly Money";
          break;
        case "10":
          currnc = "No money for you!";
          break;
        default:
          currnc = "You screwed up."; 
    }

    document.getElementById("goonga").innerHTML = currnc;
</script>
```

Since it actually does display "You screwed up" I'm pretty sure the issue comes from the random number generator but I don't know what the issue is. My other question is how is this optimized? I remember a friend of mine ranting about some dude that used else if instead of this and I thought that this must be really optimized compared to it. Even in the articles where I learned this, they say this is a better alternative to else if. The thing is if I did this with else if it would take an equal to less amount of space. I understand that not every optimization is about space, but then why is it better? I appreciate all responses.

Comment: `rngab`  is a number...your cases are strings. Remove the quotes from the numeric cases and likely will work (or find a new bug)

Comment: With that many cases a hashmap object would be cleaner and easier to maintain

Comment: `rngab` is number change it to string, it will work.

Comment: Don’t forgot to up-vote and Accept my answer as the solution if that’s resolves your issue?. Thanks –

Comment: The thing is, I already did it to another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the random generator is returning you an integer and Youre using string in case.
so convert your number to string or change the cases to number

```html
<p id="goonga"></p>

<script>

    

    var currnc = ""
    
    var rngab = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    switch (rngab.toString()){

        case "1":

        currnc = "Yen";

        break;


        case "2":

        currnc = "Dollar";
        
        break;


        case "3":

        currnc = "Peso";
        
        break;


        case "4":

        currnc = "Pound";
        
        break;

        case "5":

        currnc = "Bolivar";
        
        break;

        case "6":

        currnc = "Rupee";
        
        break;

        case "7":

        currnc = "Euro";
        
        break;

        case "8":

        currnc = "Bitcoin";
        
        break;


        case "9":

        currnc = "Monopoly Money";
        
        break;


        case "10":

        currnc = "No money for you!";
        
        break;
       
        default:

        currnc = "You screwed up."; 
    }

    document.getElementById("goonga").innerHTML = currnc;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting numbers from `Math floor` but you are using string as `case`

Also use `.textContent` instead of using `.innerHTML` its not recemened to use innerHTML to change the text of div only.

Read more about `.textContent` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) on MDN

Run Snippet below to see it working.

```js
var currnc = ""

//Function
function someFunction() {

  var rngab = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

  switch (rngab) {

    case 1:

      currnc = "Yen";

      break;


    case 2:

      currnc = "Dollar";

      break;


    case 3:

      currnc = "Peso";

      break;


    case 4:

      currnc = "Pound";

      break;

    case 5:

      currnc = "Bolivar";

      break;

    case 6:

      currnc = "Rupee";

      break;

    case 7:

      currnc = "Euro";

      break;

    case 8:

      currnc = "Bitcoin";

      break;


    case 9:

      currnc = "Monopoly Money";

      break;


    case 10:

      currnc = "No money for you!";

      break;

    default:

      currnc = "You screwed up.";
  }

}

//Calling that function
someFunction()

document.getElementById("goonga").textContent = currnc;
```

```css
* {
  background: #F2F2B6;
}
```

```html
<div id="goonga"></div>
```

Comment: Also, here the 'default' case won't ever execute right? so is it something to be considered as dead code and to be removed? forgive my ignorance

Comment: @Santa It neither of of the case matches with its condition - 'Yes' the default will be executed. Its just works like a last `else` in any `if` condition.

Comment: Got it, but in this specific case, always it falls under 'case 1 to case 10' right? do we still have to keep 'default'?

Comment: @Santa In this not required but no harm in keeping it there as a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement first evaluates its expression. It then looks for the first case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as the result of the input expression (using the strict comparison, ===) and transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements. (If multiple cases match the provided value, the first case that matches is selected, even if the cases are not equal to each other.)

more on., https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

```html
<p id="goonga"></p>

<script>

    var currnc = ""
    
    var rngab = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    switch (rngab){

        case 1:

        currnc = "Yen";

        break;


        case 2:

        currnc = "Dollar";
        
        break;

        case 3:

        currnc = "Peso";
        
        break;


        case 4:

        currnc = "Pound";
        
        break;

        case 5:

        currnc = "Bolivar";
        
        break;

        case 6:

        currnc = "Rupee";
        
        break;

        case 7:

        currnc = "Euro";
        
        break;

        case 8:

        currnc = "Bitcoin";
        
        break;


        case 9:

        currnc = "Monopoly Money";
        
        break;


        case 10:

        currnc = "No money for you!";
        
        break;
       
        default:

        currnc = "You screwed up."; 
    }

    document.getElementById("goonga").innerHTML = currnc;
</script>
```